# Detect no navigation in windows 8 metro

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'am developping  my first windows 8 application. I need to detect if the user has stopped navigation  since 3 minutes and redirect to the home page.

Do you have any ideas how to do this(i use XAML in this application)??

Best regards

Comment: how are you coding this?  using MVVM or with code-behind?  Could you provide a code sample of how you navigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start a timer in your `OnNavigatedTo` function.
- Reset the timer in the `OnNavigatedFrom` function.
- When the timer expires navigate back

You can use a `DispatcherTimer`:

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
    timer.Tick += (s,e) => GoBack();
    timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

The first is to use [Reactive Extensions](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc32).

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

    // create a single event in 10 seconds time
    var observable = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Timestamp();

    // raise exception if no event received within 9 seconds
    var observableWithTimeout = Observable.Timeout(observable, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9));

    using (observableWithTimeout.Subscribe(
        x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Timestamp), 
        ex => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", ex.Message, DateTime.Now)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The second way is to create a timer that checks the current date versus the date you recorded the last navigation activity. It's far less efficient than RX, but you may prefer it. I would put the timer in App.XAML.cs so it is globally handled for you. Easier that way.

```
var _Timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
_Timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
{
    if (m_LastNavigationDate.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)) < DateTime.Now)
        RaiseTimeout();
};
_Timer.Start();
```

Either will work